# how to connect different location database of Tally Server 6 with tally.ERP 9 to excel?

Tags: excel, connection, real-time, tally

Our Tally Geteway Server 6 and Tally Data Server or location is not same pc. I mean both are different pc with different IP. in the tally.ini file

> ;; ** Tally Gateway Server=server:port
> Tally Gateway Server=192.168.47.105:9999

And Data location is

> ;;Specify location of Data files
> Data=\192.168.47.90\Data$

Problem is when I'm trying to connect database through ODBC with Tally.ERP 9 5.3.8 to Excel 365 its showing error with no error message. If I try to connect only with username password is blank its showing Data tables name but when I'm trying to read table data its showing error. By giving username and password its showing nothing Just error.

Please help. Thanks in Advance

Comment: how your connecting, through ODBC or PowerQuery?? 
and post your full configuration

Comment: Tally Getway Server 6 and Tally.ERP9 5.3.8 to Excel 365

Comment: Your answer is very far from what I asked

Comment: I have updated my post according to your question. I'm trying to Connect with ODBC. Don't know is it possible to connect with PowerQuery. I've seen some tutorials in youtube their they connect with ODBC then transform in PowerQuery.

Comment: You are in Same network connection(LAN)?

Comment: Yes, same network connections. already using tally for entry data and exporting report to excel.

Comment: Did you configured ODBC in Tally? Post your full configuration and error you are getting

Comment: Yes I have configured ODBC, after that I tried to connect. full configuration written in the post. No error message is showing. Just written Error: